# Layer Circumference Length in Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Any idea how to get the Circumference length of the shapes in a layer in MapBox/Leaflet.js? I managed to get the area using [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/show-polygon-area/) (even though it is sometimes negative!?). It does not have circumference/perimeter though.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with [turf.line-distance](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_line-distance.html)?

Comment: You could use the haversine formula to calculate distance between points and then sum each distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula Here's my implementation in JS https://gist.github.com/sabas/967219ce4453c01de4bf

Answer (score 2):

For `L.Circle` you can calculate the circumference from it's radius:

```
L.Circle.include({
    circumference: function () {
        return 2 * Math.PI * this.getRadius();
    }
});

var circle = new L.Circle(...),
    circumference = circle.circumference();
```

For `L.Polyline` you'll need to sum the distances between the `L.LatLng` objects:

```
L.Polyline.include({
    length: function () {
        var latlngs = this.getLatLngs();
        var length = 0;
        for (var i = 0, n = latlngs.length - 1; i< n; i++) {
            length += latlngs[i].distanceTo(latlngs[i+1]);
        }
        return length;
    }
});

var polyline = new L.Polyline(...),
    length = polyline.length();
```

For `L.Polygon` which is extended from `L.Polyline` you call the length function of `L.Polyline` and add the distance between the first and last `L.LatLng` objects:

```
L.Polygon.include({
    circumference: function () {
        var length = L.Polyline.prototype.length.call(this);
        var latlngs = this.getLatLngs();
        if (latlngs.length > 2) {
            length += latlngs[0].distanceTo(latlngs[latlngs.length - 1]);
        }
        return length;
    }
});

var polygon = new L.Polygon(...),
    circumference = polygon.circumference();
```

Comment: Simple and no need for extra library, I like that! :-) By the way, you probably meant `var length = L.Polyline…` in `L.Polygon.include`

Comment: Edited. Thanks for spotting @ghybs :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and comments. Seems like [turf.js](http://turfjs.org) is the way to go, as suggested by @ghybs. It still requires some coding for anything that's not a LineString, but at least the algorithms are efficient.

Comment: iH8's answer has the merit of simplicity (in particular no need to convert to LineString) and no need for extra library. IMHO it is worth checking if it fits your need.

Comment: The data are very complex export from a GIS system, there's nothing simple there, It's all Polygons, MultiPolygons and MultiLineStrings :-)